# Problem with IIF function in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, iif

Good morning all,
I need your help !

I am working in Microsoft Access with ODBC database.

I want to fill in the blank in many fields, I have 6 columns and sometimes it happened to me that I have no items in SSCDT (sub-conditioning) , I want when I have no items in SSCDT, replace them with items in CDT (conditioning)

I created this code and since I modified the part (IIF) of SSCDT I have this error:

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOC1_PRO.MOTCLE AS CODPRO, SOC1_PRO.CODUNI AS UV, Min(Round((SOC1_TSC.PRXTAR*0.85),2)) AS PV1, IIF(MAX(IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='SAC', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' '))=' ', MAX(IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='CAR', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' ')) ,MAX(IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='SAC', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' '))) AS SSCDT, Min(SOC1_TSC.PRXTAR) AS PV2, MAX(IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='CAR', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' ')) AS CDT, Min(SOC1_PRO.NOMPRO) AS Désignation
FROM (SOC1_PRO AS SOC1_PRO INNER JOIN SOC1_TSC ON SOC1_PRO.CODPRO = SOC1_TSC.CODPRO) INNER JOIN SOC1_PRU ON SOC1_TSC.CODPRO = SOC1_PRU.CODPRO
WHERE (((SOC1_TSC.DATFIN)=' ') AND ((SOC1_TSC.CODSOC)='1') AND ((SOC1_TSC.DATDEB)>='20210000') AND ((SOC1_PRO.CODZN6)<>'N') AND ((SOC1_TSC.CODDEV)='EUR')) AND (SOC1_PRU.CODUNI = 'SAC' OR SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='CAR')
GROUP BY SOC1_PRO.MOTCLE, SOC1_PRO.CODUNI;
```

For exemple :
[image]

I hope i be clear with my explanation

Thank you ! <3

Comment: Start with replacing all the `' '` with _Null_ and check for `Is Null`. Then remove the `IIf`s until success. Then debug the offending `IIf` expression.

Comment: Thank you the offending iif it's : 'IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='CAR', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' ')'

Comment: Okay I resolve my problem I have just replace this 'IIF(SOC1_PRU.CODUNI='CAR', SOC1_PRU.COEFUV,' ')' by this : 'CDT' and it's works !